# how can i set the onclick event of append button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

how can i set the click event to appended button, i've treid some code but they didnt' work, so when i click on the button he didn't take the href that i had gave to it, he take the action of post not get

necessary part in my page commandes.blade.php

```
tbodyclasssol.append('<tr>............<td><input type="text" name="varietesol'+y+'" id="varietesol'+y+'"/></td><td><input type="text" name="gpssol'+y+'" id="gpssol'+y+'"/></td><td><input type="text" class="multiselect" name="analysedemandesol'+y+'" id="analysedemandesol'+y+'"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnanalyse" onclick="location.href="{{url('gestion_clients/index')}}"">Choisir</button></td></tr>');
```

The button take the post event that are not for it , it's for an other button:

[image]

Comment: why `type=submit` if there's no form?

Answer (score 0):

Add class "_action_input" to your input box for append button dynamically

In js code:

```
// add button after input box on click of that
$(document).on('click', '._action_input', function(){
     $(this).after('<button class="_appended_button">Choisir</button>');
});

$(document).on('click', '._appended_button', function(){
    //your code to on click action of the appended button
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If the button has a type `submit`, it will try to submit (via a `POST` request) the data. You should change your button type to `button`

Comment: not working, when I click it's like I did not give it any action

Comment: i resolved the probleme br ``` onclick="location.href="{{url('gestion_clients/index')}}"" ``` i delete the last "